# How to keep the order of JSON numeric keys in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

```
var json = `{"3":0,"2":0,"1":0}`
var obj = JSON.parse(json)
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
console.log(json === JSON.stringify(obj))
```

output

```
{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0}
false
```

I expect to get it

```
{"3":0,"2":0,"1":0}
true
```

How to do

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key

Comment: in this case you can simply print them backwards

Comment: how do you access the keys later?

Comment: "Talk is cheap, show me the code.", Stackoverflow is not a MacDonald drive-through.

Comment: I would do this: `json = "{\"3\":0,\"2\":0,\"1\":0}"; obj = JSON.parse(json); json = JSON.stringify(obj); console.log(json === JSON.stringify(obj));`. But there is still no guarantee that it will *always* be true. You should write your own "stringify" function.

Answer (score 4):

This is because `json` is an object after parsing and object's keys are not guaranteed to be in order

You can use map & it [guarantees the order of the keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Objects_and_maps_compared)

Comment: It is not correct. object keys also guaranteed order, but keys as index is order by alphabet , other keys can keep insertion order.https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible. In ES6, the keys are traversed in the following order:

> - First, the keys that are integer indices, in ascending numeric order.
> - Then, all other string keys, in the order in which they were added to the object.
> - Lastly, all symbol keys, in the order in which they were added to the object.

The integer keys are sorted in ascending order irrespective of the order in which they are inserted

```js
var a = {};
a[3] = "three"
a[2] = "two"
a[1] = "one"

console.log(JSON.stringify(a))
```

[Reference](http://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html#traversing-the-own-keys-of-an-object)

You might also want to read: [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795)

Comment: you could at least write a method which handles this stuff, but yes, its not possible just by using `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: @messerbill Even if you add each key manually in descending order, `JSON.stringify(obj)` will always have `1` in the beginning

Comment: yes of course, but like i said - you could write a custom method using `map` for example

Answer (score 0):

You can use array of objects with guid property

```js
const text = '[{"id":3,"value":0},{"id":2,"value":0},{"id":1,"value":0}]'

const json = JSON.parse(text)

console.log(JSON.stringify(json))
```

Comment: this does not satisfy the OP's needs

Comment: Json comes from an external system and I can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could spend the keys a dot and by iteratong these keys are in the original insertation order, but not accessable with just the number. This needs a dot as well.

```js
var json = `{"3.":0,"2.":0,"1.":0}`
var obj = JSON.parse(json)

console.log(obj[2])
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
console.log(json === JSON.stringify(obj))
```